# Azure AD B2C with Azure AD Multi-Tenant - option to always choose MS account to login with?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using the Azure AD multi-tenant Custom Policy found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga) with Azure B2C for sign in. The issue I am running into is that the system is overly eager to sign in a User when the sign in button is clicked. What I mean by that is if there is a single Azure AD Cookie loaded and found, then B2C tries to log that user in immediately, and if it is not an Azure AD Tenant that is authorized by the custom policy, then B2C loops them back to the sign in screen.

I am basing my cookie knowledge on the diagram found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-overview (please correct me if I am wrong).

I know that to fix this problem we can, for example, visit portal.office.com and login, which sets another cookie, then upon return to B2C the user signs in again and is greeted by an account selector screen, and can choose the authorized one.

What I would like to do is to **always** give them this option to choose which account they are signing in with, to avoid this problem. I've noticed on https://portal.azure.com when signing in, I am always (or almost always) greeted with the
[account selector screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5AbF.png).

Is there a way I can add this screen as part of the User Journey/Custom Policy? Is there an endpoint I can hit to show this screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a solution figured out using Jas' solution above that will also work with MSAL.JS 1.x.x and using the sid (or login_hint) as well (I am using the sid). The issue I was running into was when acquireTokenSilent was called, rather than authenticating silently, it was redirecting to the account select prompt in the browser.

Basically the problem with the silent auth/iframe approach (acquireTokenSilent) is that when the default of account_select is chosen, even a prompt value of 'none' sent by MSAL.js is ignored by B2C and it always chooses the "default" of account_select as specified in the prompt. This may be due to me using "IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling" = true in order to get the sid that I am passing in from MSAL.js, if present, which I didn't have the option of removing.

On the MSAL.js side, I initially thought it would be as easy as passing in an extraQueryParameter of prompt=none with the acquireTokenSilent call, and it would set the 'prompt' string claim that I created and pass that in to the AzureAD IdP claims provider. However, it still wasn't happening. I believe the MSAL.js library may have been sending this already too.

After a bit of investigation using Application Insights I set up for B2C, I was able to see during the UserJourney that the prompt parameter of 'none' I was sending in was getting changed by B2C to 'PromptQueryStringValue' (perhaps some kind of reserved word) and then the prompt claim was always set to select_account after that. I originally assumed using 'default' in the inputClaim for the Azure AD IdP but not using AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" would cause the prompt I passed in to be used, else if it was empty, use the account_select one. This wasn't the case, again perhaps because I was using IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling = true to get the OAUTH-KV sid I was passing in.

The solution was to use a custom name for the parameter/claim instead and set a default value for it on my own if it wasn't present. Now it works every time. I added a GetInitialClaims OrchestrationStep to my UserJourney, prior to the CombinedSignInAndSignUp step. This will load the prompt if present, or set a default value. Then, I simply pass that value into the IdP. Here are some code snippets:

B2C Custom Policy:

```html
...
<ClaimType Id="azureAdPrompt">
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <AdminHelpText>prompt querystring value sent to Azure Ad</AdminHelpText>
</ClaimType>
<ClaimType Id="nullBooleanClaim">
  <DisplayName>nullBoolClaim</DisplayName>
  <DataType>boolean</DataType>
  <AdminHelpText>A policy claim to store output values from ClaimsTransformations that aren't useful. This claim should not be used in TechnicalProfiles.</AdminHelpText>
  <UserHelpText>A policy claim to store output values from ClaimsTransformations that aren't useful. This claim should not be used in TechnicalProfiles.</UserHelpText>
</ClaimType>
... ...
<TechnicalProfile Id="GetInitialClaims">
  <DisplayName>Checks for prompt value, or sets a default</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="azureAdPrompt" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:azureAdPrompt}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="azureAdPrompt" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="SetAzureAdPromptDefaultValueIfEmpty" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
...
<ClaimsTransformation Id="SetAzureAdPromptDefaultValueIfEmpty" TransformationMethod="SetClaimsIfStringsMatch">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="azureAdPrompt" TransformationClaimType="claimToMatch" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="matchTo" DataType="string" Value="" />
    <InputParameter Id="stringComparison" DataType="string" Value="ordinalIgnoreCase" />
    <InputParameter Id="outputClaimIfMatched" DataType="string" Value="select_account" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="azureAdPrompt" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="nullBooleanClaim" TransformationClaimType="stringCompareResultClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
...
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="GetInitialClaims" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GetInitialClaims" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
  ... ...
</OrchestrationStep>


<!-- Values for Azure Ad IdP below: -->
...
<Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
...
<InputClaims>
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sid" PartnerClaimType="sid" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:sid}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="azureAdPrompt" PartnerClaimType="prompt" />
</InputClaims>
...
```

MSAL.js side:

```js
getAccessToken = () => {
  if (account.sid) {
    const ssoRequest: AuthenticationParameters = {
      sid: account.sid,
      extraQueryParameters: {
        azureAdPrompt: 'none'
      }
    };
    return this._msal.ssoSilent(ssoRequest)
      .then(response => {
        const tokenRequest: AuthenticationParameters = {
          scopes: this._scopes,
          sid: response.idToken.sid,
          extraQueryParameters: {
            azureAdPrompt: 'none'
          }
        };
        return this._msal.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest)
          .then(accessTokenResponse => {
            return accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this._msal.acquireTokenRedirect(tokenRequest);
            return '';
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const onErrorTokenRequest: AuthenticationParameters = {
          scopes: this._scopes
        };
        this._msal.loginRedirect(onErrorTokenRequest);
        return '';
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Add an input claim like this and add it to your AAD IdP claims provider:

```xml
 <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="prompt" PartnerClaimType="prompt" defaultValue= "select_account"/>
      </InputClaims>
```

And define a claim called “prompt”, with type string.

This instructs AAD B2C to send the prompt param to AAD when the user selects to login with AAD. At AAD they’ll get the account selection screen.

At AAD B2C, if a AAD B2C cookie is found, and a matching claims provider technical profile ID is found, then AAD B2C auto forwards the user to that federated Idp. If the user arrives  otherwise to AAD B2C, they’ll be presented with the normal sign in screen.

To force a different behaviour, you can send a prompt param: &prompt=login or &prompt=select_account, which will ignore any AAD B2C session cookies.

AAD and AAD B2C cookies are independent and one does not know about the others cookies.

Comment: Thanks @Jas Suri, this is the exact solution I need! I have found another issue unfortunately: I am also using MSAL.js and in the AAD claims provider I am also using the sid claim as follows:
`<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sid" PartnerClaimType="sid" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:sid}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" /> `
It seems that the 'prompt=none' is not getting used with silent auth (the DefaultValue of "select_account" is always chosen). Is this due to 
`<Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>` being turned on?

Comment: This will be a side effect, the silent calls will now fail since you’re telling B2C to always send “prompt=select_account” to AAD. The soln only works fully for Web Apps where an iframe is not used for SSO/SilentToken calls.

Comment: Ok, I might try to figure out a custom fix for that. Thanks again! One last question if you don't mind: do you know when PKCE support with MSAL.js will work with B2C? I haven't been able to find anything about it on their site.

Comment: It works now, just use latest msal.js 2.x. Here’s the guidance [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-spa#migrate-from-the-implicit-flow)

Comment: Oh, that is great to know. Thanks so much for all your help!!

Comment: Hi @Jas I figured out my custom solution, see below. I am curious if MSAL 2.x will resolve this problem, I imagine it would.

Comment: This is the working solution for me, but with some minor attentions. For those who encountered some validation issues like me:
- `DefaultValue` should be in CamelCase
- You have to add one more claim type to the base file